# Using user message in retryPrompt

Tags: node.js, botframework

In a given moment, my bot asks for a number.

```
builder.Prompts.number(session, "Cool. What's the number?", {
    retryPrompt: "I couldn't understand $%#@. Could you type it again?"
});
```

I need the message to contain the user response instead of `$%#@`. Is there a way to do it?  I tried to use `session.message.text` and `results.response`, but these are still from the outer function because of closure.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this answer: currently, there is no way to change the message inside the Prompt dialog.

I looked up the code for [BotFramework for node](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node/core/)The message you send as `retryPrompt` is as is, without replacements.